# Use generated identity for another column within the same insert only sometimes

Tags: sql, sql-server

All similar questions are suggesting solutions for full copy of one column to another but that isn't my requirement.

Basically I'm adding say employees and while adding I have the option to make them a teamlead(of a new team). 
There is a teamlead id column which stores the employee id of the teamlead for each employee.

So while adding an employee who is going to be a teamlead, his teamlead column should hold his just generated employee id.

Is it possible to do that in a single insert? Someone said the value generation is done after the execution of the insert. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Edit: I don't have a working for a single insert. Right now I'm inserting and updating like this:

```
declare @TLID int
CREATE TABLE employees (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    Name varchar(255),
    TeamLeadID int
);

if(@isTeamLead=1) --stored procedure parameter
begin
insert into employees(name)
values('Mark')
select @TLID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
update employees set TeamLeadID=@TLID where id=@TLID
end
else 
begin
insert into employees(name,TeamLeadID)
values('Mark',16)
end
```

Wondering if a single insert can work for the first case.

Comment: I think you are looking for `scope_identity`

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: You should edit this post and add the code or asking best

Comment: I've added now.

Answer (score 6):

No you can't do this with a single insert.

You would need an insert then an update back to the same row to set the other column value back to the just inserted `IDENTITY` column value.

But there are some other approaches you can use.

You could use a sequence rather than an identity. Then you will know the value before insert and can simply use it in both columns.

Or you could just have `NULL` for the `teamleadid` column for employees that are team leads. And potentially use `ISNULL(teamleadid, id)` to calculate the result either as a computed column or at `SELECT` time.